# Check whether a cell matches multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm struggling to format a VLOOKUP to work the way I need it to. #N/A's are all over the place.

I'm probably using something entirely incorrectly and not as intended.

I have the following data:

```
Windows Version Table - AA2:AD3450
Hardware Model Column - P2:P85
Accepted SKU - M2:M55

Client Name - Sheet1 Cell A2:A9000
Client Model - Shee1 Cell J2:J9000
Client Area - Sheet1 Cell B2:B9000
Client OS - Sheet1 Cell E2:E9000
```

I need to identify the following

- IF 'Windows Version' resides in 'Client OS' and 'Hardware Model' matches 'Client Model' output 'Client Name' to column AG AND output 'Client Area' to column AH AND output 'Client OS' to Column AI

I hope this makes a little sense. Ive been trying to figure this one out for a while.

**Data Ref Table:**

[image]

**Client Information Table**

[image]

**Expected output**

[image]

Comment: Can you post a data example? your input and expected output

Comment: Here is a link to an example workbook. Not sure how else to share, apologies https://file.io/eRPBJDdQIBNx

Comment: Have updated post with extra images as excel document probably wasn't ideal

Comment: How do you validate OS? Also, as per data provide `name 9` and `name 4` do not meet model requirement.

Comment: In this case, does the string contain "Windows 7" would be the check criteria. My mistake with name 9, that would be incorrect as CPU SKU is 5. My mistake on this one, was a long day when I made it.

Comment: Can't understand what you mean with «IF 'Windows Version' resides in 'Client OS'». The headers of the Client Information Table are cut. Do we have to read the last part of their headers to know the "Windows Version"? No table has a reference about their address: in what sheet are they placed? In which columns? In which rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Requirement:** Validate records in `lo.DATA` table against `lo.Clients` table and output `valid` and `invalid` records in two separated tables `lo.Ok` and `lo.Error`.
***Note:** A valid record must have `Client OS`= `7` as per OP.*

`lo.DATA` table, located at `[B11:F21]` and `lo.Clients` table, located at `[H11:M15]`
[image]

[VLOOKUP function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1): This function has limitations when it comes to the use of criteria, therefore I suggest to use it only for straight matches. We’ll use this function in the tables `lo.Ok` and `lo.Error` to return the associated values once the record compliance have been identified.

**Criteria:**

*Client OS:*
`= lo.DATA[@[Client OS]] = 7`   *Client OS must be 7 as per OP (change as required).*

[MATCH function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a): Use this function to validate record compliance of Model & SKU.
*Client Model:*
`= MATCH( lo.DATA[Client Model], lo.Clients[Model], 0 )`

*SKU:*
`= MATCH( lo.DATA[SKU], lo.Clients[SKU], 0 )`

[image]

**Multiple Criteria:**

*Formula:*

```
= ( ( lo.DATA[Client OS] = 7 )
 * ( MATCH( lo.DATA[Client Model], lo.Clients[Model], 0 ) > 0 )
 * ( MATCH( lo.DATA[SKU], lo.Clients[SKU], 0 ) > 0 ) )
```

[AGGREGATE function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aggregate-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df): Use this function to return a list of the valid\invalid records after applying the corresponding multiple criteria.

Use the `Array form` of the function `AGGREGATE(function_num, options, array, [k])`, were:

*AGGREGATE function parameters:*
`function_num` = `15` (SMALL)
`options` = `6` (Ignore error values)
`array` =

```
( ( lo.DATA[Client OS] = 7 )
 * ( MATCH( lo.DATA[Client Model], lo.Clients[Model], 0 ) > 0 )
 * ( MATCH( lo.DATA[SKU], lo.Clients[SKU], 0 ) > 0 ) )’
```

`[k]` =  `ROWS([Col$Row:ColRow)`  ([ROWS function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/rows-function-b592593e-3fc2-47f2-bec1-bda493811597) `ColRow`= Address of the 1st cell where the formula is entered, i.e. `ROWS(W$12:W12)` )

This is the resulting formula:

```
= AGGREGATE( 15, 6,
 ( ( lo.DATA[Client OS] = 7 )
 * ( MATCH( lo.DATA[Client Model], lo.Clients[Model], 0 ) > 0 )
 * ( MATCH( lo.DATA[SKU], lo.Clients[SKU], 0 ) > 0 ) ),
 ROWS(W$12:W12) )
```

[image]

Although the AGGREGATE function returns the valid record, it misses the position of the records. To obtain the position use the [ROW function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/row-function-3a63b74a-c4d0-4093-b49a-e76eb49a6d8d)

`ROW (Col:Col)`  *(i.e. Col= Column where the formula is entered)*

This is the resulting formula:

```
= AGGREGATE( 15, 6,
  ROW(AA:AA) / ( ( lo.DATA[Client OS] = 7 )
 * ( MATCH( lo.DATA[Client Model], lo.Clients[Model], 0 ) > 0 )
 * ( MATCH( lo.DATA[SKU], lo.Clients[SKU], 0 ) > 0 ) ),
 ROWS(AA$12:AA12) )
```

[image]

**MULTI-CRITERIA Formula**

Finally, use the [INDEX function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) to return the corresponding record from the `lo.DATA' table.

```
= IFERROR( INDEX( lo.DATA[Client Name], AGGREGATE( 15, 6,
 ROW(AC:AC) / ( ( lo.DATA[Client OS] = 7 )
 * ( MATCH( lo.DATA[Client Model], lo.Clients[Model], 0 ) > 0 )
 * ( MATCH( lo.DATA[SKU], lo.Clients[SKU], 0 ) > 0 ) ),
 ROWS(AC$12:AC12) ) ), "" )
```

[image]

**Proposed Solution:**
Please ensure the consistency of the headers among the tables, this is key for the `VLOOKUP` formulas to return the correct values.

**Valid record in table `lo.Ok`, located at `[AL11:AP21]`**

*Formulas*

*Client Name:*

```
= IFERROR( INDEX( lo.DATA[Client Name], AGGREGATE( 15, 6,
 ROW(AL:AL) / ( ( lo.DATA[Client OS] = 7 )
 * ( MATCH( lo.DATA[Client Model], lo.Clients[Model], 0 ) > 0 )
 * ( MATCH( lo.DATA[SKU], lo.Clients[SKU], 0 ) > 0 ) ),
 ROWS(AL$12:AL12) ) ), "" )
```

*Client Model, Client Area, SKU,Client OS:*
Enter this formula in `[AM12]` then copy to `[AM12:AP21]`

```
= IFERROR( VLOOKUP( [@[Client Name]], lo.DATA25,
 MATCH( AM$11, lo.DATA[#Headers], 0 ), 0 ), "" )
```

[image]

**Invalid record in table `lo.Error`, located at `[AT11:AY21]`**

*Formulas*

*Client Name:*
The validation is performed against the `lo.Ok` table, (i.e. a record from `lo.DATA` is `invalid` if it is `not found` in `lo.Ok`).

```
= IFERROR( INDEX( lo.DATA[Client Name], AGGREGATE( 15, 6,
 ROW(AT:AT) / ISERROR( MATCH( lo.DATA[Client Name], Lo.OK[Client Name], 0 ) ),
 ROWS(AT$12:AT12) ) ), "" )
```

*Client Model, Client Area, SKU, Client OS:*
Enter this formula in `[AU12]` then copy to `[AX12:AP21]`

```
= IFERROR( VLOOKUP( [@[Client Name]], lo.DATA,
 MATCH( AU$11, lo.DATA[#Headers], 0 ), 0 ), "" )
```

*Status:*

```
= IF( LEN([@[Client Name]])=0, "",
 SUBSTITUTE( CONCATENATE( "Error in: ,",
 IF( [@[Client OS]] <> 7, ", OS", "" ),
 IF( ISERROR( MATCH( [Client Model], lo.Clients.A[Model], 0 ) ), ", Model", "" ),
 IF( ISERROR( MATCH( [SKU], lo.Clients.A[SKU], 0 ) ), ", SKU", "" ) ), ",,", "" ) )
```

[image]