# using Vlookup to get multiple matching rows from a common column across two sheets

Tags: excel, vlookup, matching

**i have first sheet below**

[image]

**i have second sheet below**

[image]

**I want the result to be**

[image]

> `tried Vlookup function several ways but not able to get entire row.

Comment: VLOOKUP needs the lookup value in the first column of the lookup table. XLOOKUP doesn't have that need but isn't available in older versions of Excel. The result you want is a copy of Sheet2 with an extra column inserted on the left. The extra column looks up the value of what will then be column B in column B of Sheet1. So, if you have it, use XLOOKUP. If you don't have it, use INDEX/MATCH or switch columns to use VLOOKUP.

Comment: You give us the result, but you don't explain what your lookup vakye is. Which of the result cells are to be looked up with a formula??  VLookup may not be the best approach for this. In fact, formulas may not be the best approach at all. This is a piece of cake to do with Power Query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `Excel Tables` are located as follows:

| Table | Sheet | Address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Table1 | Sht(1) | B2:C4 |
| Table2 | Sht(2) | B2:F12 |
| Results | Sht(0) | B2:G12 |

Enter these formulas in Table `Results`:
Field: `Name`

```
= IFERROR( INDEX( Table2[Name], AGGREGATE( 15, 6, ROW(D:D) /  
  ( ( MATCH( Table2[Id], Table1[Id], 0 ) > 0 ) * 1 ),
  ROWS(D$3:D3) ) ), TEXT(,) )
```

Field: `Id`

```
= IFERROR( INDEX( Table2[Id], MATCH( [@Name], Table2[Name], 0 ) ), TEXT(,) )
```

Field: `Program`

```
= IFERROR( INDEX( Table1[Program], MATCH( [@Id], Table1[Id], 0 ) ), TEXT(,) )
```

Field: `Maths`

```
=IFERROR( INDEX( Table2[Maths], MATCH( [@Name], Table2[Name], 0 ) ), TEXT(,) )
```

Field: `Science`

```
=IFERROR( INDEX( Table2[Science], MATCH( [@Name], Table2[Name], 0 ) ), TEXT(,) )
```

Field: `English`

```
=IFERROR( INDEX( Table2[English], MATCH( [@Name], Table2[Name], 0 ) ), TEXT(,) )
```

[image]

If your are not using `Excel Tables` use this formulas:

Field: `Name`

```
= IFERROR( INDEX( 'Sht(2)'!$C$3:$C$12, AGGREGATE( 15, 6, ROW(D:D) /
  ( ( MATCH( 'Sht(2)'!$B$3:$B$12, 'Sht(1)'!$C$3:$C$4, 0 ) > 0 ) * 1 ),
  ROWS(D$3:D3) ) ), TEXT(,) )
```

Field `Id`

```
= IFERROR( INDEX( 'Sht(2)'!$B$3:$B$12, MATCH( 'Sht(3)'!$D3, 'Sht(2)'!$C$3:$C$12, 0 ) ), TEXT(,) )
```

Field `Program`

```
= IFERROR( INDEX( 'Sht(1)'!$B$3:$B$4, MATCH( 'Sht(3)'!$C3, 'Sht(1)'!$C$3:$C$4, 0 ) ), TEXT(,) )
```

Field `Maths`

```
=IFERROR( INDEX( 'Sht(2)'!$D$3:$D$12, MATCH( 'Sht(3)'!$D3, 'Sht(2)'!$C$3:$C$12, 0 ) ), TEXT(,) )
```

Field `Science`

```
=IFERROR( INDEX( 'Sht(2)'!$E$3:$E$12, MATCH( 'Sht(3)'!$D3, 'Sht(2)'!$C$3:$C$12, 0 ) ), TEXT(,) )
```

Field `English`

```
=IFERROR( INDEX( 'Sht(2)'!$F$3:$F$12, MATCH( 'Sht(3)'!$D3, 'Sht(2)'!$C$3:$C$12, 0 ) ), TEXT(,) )
```

Explanation about the functions used can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65935584/check-whether-a-cell-matches-multiple-criteria/66013081#66013081), and in this pages:
[AGGREGATE function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aggregate-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df)
[INDEX function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd)
[MATCH function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a)